# Will this function correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, minecraft

Just made this in a couple of seconds.... I don't know much about Bash, im still learning.. but i was wondering if this was going to work or not.. and if it will not work, what can I do to make it work correctly?

explanation of what i want this to do...

create a ZIP backup of the entire world folder, and create the zip under backups directory, and have the naming convention be...
world_(the current date and time as $(date) prints out except all spaces replaced with under scored)

```
 zip -r /backups/world_${$(date)// /_} /home/mc/world/
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: why not running `echo /backups/world_${$(date)// /_}` to check?

Comment: It won't work, first you need to get `date` in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
echo /backups/world_$(date | sed 's/ /_/g')
```

produces:

```
/backups/world_Mon_Feb__3_21:56:33_PST_2014
```

which appears to be what you want.

The problem with `${$(date)// /_}` is that the shell is expecting a shell variable inside the braces, not a text string. The solution above uses command substitution (`$(...)`) and, since `date` and `sed` are both commands, it works.

Comment: Or you can also use `date +FORMAT` syntax without `sed` itself. Something like `echo /backups/world_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M")`, which will display `/backups/world_05-02-2014_04-54`